# Can anyone explain how this comment-removing regex works?

Tags: php, regex, json, string, comments

It's one of those cases when you got something to work but surprised by how well it works. I have a little trouble understanding why the regex below, which is to remove comments from a JSON string without touching comments in string values, works in all cases practically unconditionally, no matter where and how many double quotes I put into the comments to "fool" the regex:

```
$str = <<<'ndoc'
{
    // comment "
    "prop0": /* remove */ "hello /* preserve */ there", // remove
    "prop1": /* remove " */ "hi // preserve", /* remove " */
    "prop2": /* remove */ "hi // preserve"
}
ndoc;
$str = preg_replace("/\"(?<!\\\\\")(?:[^\\\\\"]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*\"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\/\\/.*(?=\\R)|\\/\\*\\C*?\\*\\//u", "", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

http://ideone.com/rLP1nq

As I see it, the text from the double quote in the first comment and to the double quote in `prop0` had to be skipped, then `": /* remove */ "` had to be skipped, and so on, not removing comments that needs to be removed and removing text that needs to be preserved. But the regex works fine regardless. Why?

Comment: Can someone tell me what on earth 5 backslashes produces?

Comment: @OGHaza 4 backslashes in a PHP string make 2 backslashes in regex string to match (or not match) 1 backslash and `\"` (not) matches "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your source and added comments to the pattern. The delimiters are changed to (), making the escaping for the slashes unnecessary. The x modifer allows to format the pattern (whitespaces are ignored, # comments possible).

This should make the pattern more readable. You can see that the first part matches the "value"-String. If it is matched the replace is skipped otherwise the // and /**/ comments are matched and replaced.

```
$str = <<<'ndoc'
{
    // comment "
    "prop0": /* remove */ "hello /* preserve */ there", // remove
    "prop1": /* remove " */ "hi // preserve", /* remove " */
    "prop2": /* remove */ "hi // preserve"
}
ndoc;

$pattern = "(
  # a starting double quote
  \" 
  # string contents including escape sequences
  (?<!\\\\\")(?:[^\\\\\"]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)* 
  # the ending double quote
  \"
  # skip double quote string matches
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL) 
  # or
  | 
  # // comments
  //.*(?=\\R)  
  # or
  | 
  # /* */ comments
  /\\*\\C*?\\*/
)xu";

$str = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but why putting double quotes into comments randomly doesn't change what text is processed and what is skipped?

Comment: " are allowed in the respective pattern parts for the comments. The "." and "\C" allow for the double quote.

Comment: maybe I'm dumb but I still don't get why the first pair of quotes (one the comment, another at the first property name) does not get skipped and it doesn't break everything else

Comment: It already started matching the //... comment. The dot matches all chars except \n (the newline). Until the next newline, all characters will be part of this match.